# arrow notation not working in internet explorer for data.reduce

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a code

```
  data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $monthlyParticipation; ?>'),

  months1 = data.reduce((p,c) => ~p.indexOf(c.months) ? p : p.concat(c.months),[]),

  series = data.reduce((p,c) => { var f = p.find(f => f.name == c.project_title);
                               !!f ? f.data[months1.indexOf(c.months)] = c.amount*1
                                  : p.push({name: c.project_title, id:c.project_title,
                                     data: (new Array(months1.length)).fill(0).map((e,i) => i === months1.indexOf(c.months) ? c.amount*1 : e)});

                          return p; 
                 },[]);
```

Above is my complete code where I am using arrow notations. The code is working fine in all the browsers excepts IE. When I googled I found that arrow notations do not work in IE.

This is my code [**https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6pttt/**](https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6pttt/) please check in IE

Can anyone please give a solution for this. Is there any other way to write the code.

Please help!!

Comment: _"Can anyone please give a solution for this"_ Erm... Just use a plain old `function() { ... }` O.o

Comment: why don't you try using babel

Comment: I am new to jquery. This is a code which I found in google. I tried to rewrite but I am unable to convert it to old function. Could you help me

Comment: I don't know the right syntax. Could you please write it down the function

Comment: "use a real browser"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function newFilledArray(len, val) {
  var rv = new Array(len);
  while (--len >= 0) {
    rv[len] = val;
  }
  return rv;
}
data = JSON.parse('[{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"0","amount":"0","months":"Dec-2016"},{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"0","amount":"0","months":"Jan-2017"},{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"0","amount":"0","months":"Feb-2017"},{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"7845963210","amount":"85964710","months":"Mar-2017"},{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"0","amount":"0","months":"Apr-2017"},{"project_ref_id":"479","project_title":"Environment project","estimated_project_cost":"0","amount":"0","months":"May-2017"}]'),
  months1 = data.reduce(function(p, c) {
    return ~p.indexOf(c.months) ? p : p.concat(c.months)
  }, []),
  series = data.reduce(function(p, c) {
    var f = undefined;
    console.log(p);
    p.map(function(x) {
      if (x.name == c.project_title) {
        f = x;
      }
    });

    !!f ? f.data[months1.indexOf(c.months)] = c.amount * 1 :
      p.push({
        name: c.project_title,
        id: c.project_title,
        data: (
          Array.apply(null, new Array(months1.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0)
          .map(
            function(e, i) {
              return i === months1.indexOf(c.months) ? c.amount * 1 : e
            }
          ))
      });
    return p;
  }, []);
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container1'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: months1,
    title: {
      text: 'Months'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rupees'
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
          var selected = this.index;
          var allSeries = this.chart.series;
          $.each(allSeries, function(index, series) {
            selected == index ? series.show() : series.hide();
          });
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: series,
}, function(chart1) {


  $.each(chart1.series, function(i, serie) {
    var pname = serie.name;
    var pjname = pname.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g, '');
    var chartcolor = $('#container1 .highcharts-series-' + i + ' path').attr('stroke');
    if (chartcolor == 'rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)') {
      chartcolor = '#7cb5ec';
    }
    chart1.series[i].graph.attr({
      stroke: chartcolor
    });
    var $customLegend = $('.prj-label1' + pjname).css('background-color', chartcolor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I know that internet explorer does not support arrow functions, but what the solution could be for this

Comment: use normal js function is the fix ;-)

Comment: I don't know the right syntax. Could you please write it down the function

Comment: wait updated wrong code

Comment: Updated, you can check now.

Comment: Ok thank you. If I try to use it I am getting SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Comment: means p is not array, you will have to loop thru object to find value.

Comment: see the edited answer.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: p.indexOf is not a function is the error which I am getting

Comment: Please provide pen, that I can edit, I don't know what you're passing as data to var in function.

Comment: This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6pttt/ please check in IE

Comment: Hi, this is the link to fiddle, working in ie.  https://jsfiddle.net/xfwne0up/

Comment: also updated code here.

Comment: Thanks alot!!! it's working

Comment: Great!! welcome ;-)

Comment: @rjirji manual hand conversion of ES6 to ES5 is tedious and error prone that is why you should use transpilers like babel

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer does not support many ES6 features. But you can still write your code in ES6 and use transpilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert your code to ES5 so that it can run on older browsers.